# Saving data after non-Django Form submission

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a payment form that is made up of various elements.

Here my problem is that the card for a new stripe user isn't registered until after form submission.

I know that if my form has a newly added Address, I can use form.is_valid() but that doesn't apply if my address is one that is saved already. But is there a way I can set the card using `stripe.PaymentMethod.list` after the form is submitted, regardless of if the Django form is part of it?

form

```
<form method="POST" id="subscription-form" data-secret="{{client_secret}}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">Payment Details</label>
            {% if payment_methods %}
            
            <div class="form-check my-3 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment-methods" id="add-new-card"
                    value="add-new-card" onclick="addCard()" {%if payment_methods %} {%else%}checked="checked" {%endif%}
                    required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="add-new-card">
                    Add new payment method
                </label>

                <div id="new-card" style="display: none;">
                    <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs mb-2" for="cardholder-name">
                        Name on Card
                    </label>
                    <input id="cardholder-name"
                        class="mb-2 border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                        value="{{customer.name}}" detype="text">
                    <!-- placeholder for Elements -->
                    <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs  mb-2" for="card-element">
                        Card Details
                    </label>
                    <div id="card-element"
                        class="mb-2 border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="card-result"></div>
                    <div id="card-errors" class="my-2" role="alert"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
            {% if saved_customer %}
            {% for method in payment_methods %}

            <div class="form-check my-3 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment-methods" id="{{method.card}}"
                    value="{{method.id}}" onclick="hideCard()" {% if forloop.first %} checked="checked" {%endif%}>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="{{method.card}}">
                    {{method.card.brand}} ending in {{method.card.last4}}
                </label>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="form-check my-3 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="payment-methods" id="add-new-card"
                    value="add-new-card" checked="checked"
                    required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="add-new-card">
                    Add new payment method
                </label>

                <div id="new-card">
                    <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs mb-2" for="cardholder-name">
                        Name on Card
                    </label>
                    <input id="cardholder-name"
                        class="mb-2 border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                        value="{{customer.name}}" detype="text">
                    <!-- placeholder for Elements -->
                    <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs  mb-2" for="card-element">
                        Card Details
                    </label>
                    <div id="card-element"
                        class="mb-2 border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-gray-300 text-gray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150">
                        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                    </div>
                    <div id="card-result"></div>
                    <div id="card-errors" class="my-2" role="alert"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}


            <label class="block uppercase text-gray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2">Address</label>
            <div id="address-list">
                <div class="form-check my-3 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="addresses" id="new-address" value="new-address"
                        onclick="showAddress()" {%if addresses%} {%else%}checked="checked" {%endif%}>

                    <label class="form-check-label" for="new-address">
                        New Address
                    </label>
                    <span id="address-form"></span>
                </div>

                {% for address in addresses %}
                <div class="form-check my-3 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="addresses" id="{{address.id}}"
                        value="{{address.id}}" onclick="hideAddress()" {% if forloop.first %} checked="checked"
                        {%endif%} required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="{{address.id}}">
                        {{address.name}} - {{address.line_1}}
                    </label>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" id="email" name='email' value='{{customer.email}}'>



            <div>
                <p class="text-xs">By confirming, you agree that you will be charged immediately, and then monthly for
                    this product until cancelled</p>
                <button id="submit" type="submit"
                    class="w-full mt-2 bg-blue-300 text-blue-900 font-medium rounded p-3">Confirm
                    and Pay</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

view

```
@login_required
def subscription_new(request, product):
    stripe.api_key = STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    title = "New Subscription for " + product
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=product)
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
    addresses = Address.objects.filter(customer=customer)
    current_day = datetime.date.today().day
    
    # maintain order day in short months
    if current_day > 28:
        current_day = 1
    stripe_amount = str(int(round(product.price, 2) * 100))
    context = {
        'title' : title,
        'product' : product,
        'customer' : customer,
        'addresses' : addresses,
        'current_day' : current_day,
        'STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY' : STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
    }
    card = request.POST.get('payment-methods')
    if customer.stripe_id:
        payment_methods = stripe.PaymentMethod.list(
                customer=customer.stripe_id,
                type="card",
            )
        context['saved_customer'] = True
        context['payment_methods'] = payment_methods
    else:
        print('no  stripe id ')
        new_customer = stripe.Customer.create(name=customer.name, email=customer.email)    
        customer.stripe_id = new_customer.id
        customer.save()
        context['saved_customer'] = False
    intent = stripe.SetupIntent.create(customer=customer.stripe_id)
    client_secret = intent.client_secret
    context['client_secret'] = client_secret

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("method is post")
        address = request.POST.get('addresses')
        if address == 'new-address':
            form = AddressForm(request.POST)
            address = form.save(commit=False)
            address.customer = customer
            address.save()
        else:
            address = Address.objects.get(id=address)

        if customer.stripe_id:
            payment_methods = stripe.PaymentMethod.list(
                customer=customer.stripe_id,
                type="card",
            )
            print("customer has id")
            if card == "add-new-card":
                payment_methods = stripe.PaymentMethod.list(
                customer=customer.stripe_id,
                type="card",
            )
                new_card = payment_methods.data[0]
                # context['client_secret'] = client_secret
                subscription = Subscription.objects.create(customer=customer, product=product, address=address, renewal_day=current_day, payment_method=new_card.id)
                msg = 'Subscription created'
            else:
                subscription = Subscription.objects.create(customer=customer, product=product, address=address, renewal_day=current_day, payment_method=card)
                msg = 'Subscription created'
            messages.success(request, msg)
    # If method is not post
    else:
        form = AddressForm()
        context['form'] = form
   
    return render(request, 'accounts/subscription_new.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `AddressForm` is a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), you can use it on an existing instance of a model as well:

```
address = Address.objects.get(id=address_id)
form = AddressForm(request.POST, instance=address)
```

Also, you can take other actions before saving the form.  If you want the stripe payment method to be registered in order to save the form, register it first, then save the form.

If you want to customize the data stored on the address by `AddressForm`, just override the `save` method and modify `self.instance` before you call `super().save()`.

Alternatively, just edit the Address object outside of the context of the form.  There's nothing requiring database updates to happen inside a form `save` method

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to register the payment method first, since stripe only has that data after the form submits, and I can't separate the form into multiple submits.

Comment: I also see the docs on instance being available, I've used that for things like edit views but don't know how to translate that to fit into this scenario. I have it right now where I can change the field to be a new or saved address, and that decision is made with JavaScript